# Sufficient condition for being zero?

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-operator-theory

Suppose that $F:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is $L$-Lipschitz continuous (for some $L>0$) and monotone, i.e.,
\begin{align}
(\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}) \quad \| F(x) - F(y) \| \leq L \| x-y \|,
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
(\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}) \quad \langle F(x) - F(y), x-y \rangle \geq 0,
\end{align}
respectively.

Now, suppose that $\gamma \in (0,1/L)$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is such that
\begin{align}
F(x) = F(x-\gamma F(x))
\end{align}
and $x^{\star}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $F(x^{\star})=0$.

**Question**: Does this imply that $F(x) = 0$? If not, what is a counterexample?

**What I have**: I'm unsure if this is true, but I don't have a counterexample yet.

On the other hand, using monotonicity, I get that
\begin{align}
\gamma \|F(x)\|^2 \leq \langle F(x),x-x^{\star} \rangle,
\end{align}
and by Lipschitz continuity, I get that
\begin{align}
\|F(x)\| \leq L \|x-\gamma F(x) - x^{\star}\|.
\end{align}
However, I cannot show that $F(x)=0$ with these inequalities.

**Edit**: Consider $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{align}
F(x) =
\begin{cases}
x+1 & \text{if } x<-1 \\
0 & \text{if } -1\leq x< 1 \\
x-1 & \text{if } 1 \leq x < 2 \\
1 & \text{if } 2 \leq x.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then $F$ is $1$-Lipschitz continuous and monotone. Clearly $F(0) = 0$. Let $x=4$ and $\gamma = 1/2$. Then
\begin{align}
F(x) &= F(4) = 1
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
F(x-\gamma F(x)) &= F(3.5) = 1
\end{align}